# Which is the better way to get scattered partitions on Arch Linux to install for legacy (BIOS) + Btrfs + Luks encryption?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, btrfs, luks

There is in my hands, an old i3 laptop that I wanted for study and lab schooling use.  Since it is a laptop, I would like to increase the security and further install flexibility.

I'd like to have the Arch Linux installation with a boot partition and the root and home partitions separated for this legacy equipment, I mean, this machine still uses BIOS instead of UEFI. So I'm thinking in have these partitions with Luks encryption and formatting with Btrfs except for the /boot.
Which are the concerns about this plan?
Is it really worth doing? Would have I more pain than never using the encryption after the base install?

Other relevant info:
There is a 420G SSD available for use
Less than 8G of RAM

Comment: Not an answer, but in case Btrfs + LUKS does not work out in your favour: On hardware very similar to yours, I am using [fscrypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fscrypt) for home directory encryption. It provides less security, but is easy to set-up (no need for additional partitions) and seems to be reasonably light-weight.